# Interface inheritance issues

Tags: c#, interface

I have `IServiceHandler` and an `ISalesHandler` and both inherit from `Ihandler`

***IHandler.cs***

```
public interface IHandler
{
    Task AddAsync(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> toAdd, int dataFileId);
    Task AddAuditAsync(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> toAdd, int dataFileId);
}
```

***IServiceHandler.cs***

```
public interface IServiceHandler : IHandler
{
    Task<IEnumerable<ACService>> GetAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<ACServiceAudit>> GetAuditAsync();
}
```

***ISalesHandler.cs***

```
public interface ISalesHandler : IHandler
{
    Task<IEnumerable<ACSale>> GetAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<ACSaleAudit>> GetAuditAsync();
}
```

Then I have a method that returns either the Sales or Service but the problem is I am returning it as `IHandler`

```
private IHandler CreateHandler(FileType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case FileType.Sales:
            return  _container.GetExportedValue<ISalesHandler>("Sales");
        case FileType.Service:
            return _container.GetExportedValue<IServiceHandler>("Service");
        case FileType.None:
            return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

which causes me only to access the methods in the `IHandler` and not in `IServiceHandler` or `ISalesHandler`.

How can I structure the interfaces so that I can access all the methods? I would prefer to keep the `CreateHandler` method.

Comment: How would you expect the compiler to know which type was going to be returned? If I call `CreateHandler(FileType.Sales)`, the compiler isn't going to look through the method body and know that that returns an `ISalesHandler`, and that therefore `GetAsync` will return a `Task<IEnumerable<ACSale>>`. Basically you need to distinguish between compile-time information and execution-time information - the value of the parameter for `CreateHandler` is execution-time information, and so can't affect compile-time information.

Comment: Probably better if you make both the interface and CreateHandler methods generic. Then you can get back what you want without needing a switch statement.

Comment: Pass type parameter to your Createhandler method or just (IHandler as IServiceHandler)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you are returning an `IHandler`, so the methods defined there are accessible without casting.

I think it is possible to circumvent this all by using generics, since there seems to be a pattern in the deriving handlers.

Would this do for you?

*IHandler.cs*:

```
public interface IHandler // I usually split the generic and non-generic methods
{
    Task AddAsync(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> toAdd, int dataFileId);
    Task AddAuditAsync(IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> toAdd, int dataFileId);
}

public interface IHandler<TService, TServiceAudit> : IHandler
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TService>> GetAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<TServiceAudit>> GetAuditAsync();
}
```

*IServiceHandler.cs*:

```
public interface IServiceHandler : IHandler<ACService, ACServiceAudit>
{ }
```

*ISalesHandler.cs*:

```
public interface ISalesHandler : IHandler<ACSale, ACSaleAudit>
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ill quickly have a look, quick question so if i change the interface to look like yours do i still, call it the the same way as i had it in the CreateHandler method. because i think if i return Ihandler i would have the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

What about using a generic interface?

```
public interface IServiceHandler<TSale, TAudit> : IHandler
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TSale>> GetSaleAsync();
    Task<IEnumerable<TAudit>> GetAuditAsync();
}
```

I just rename your `GetAsync()` to `GetSaleAsync()` to be more explicit, but it is as you wish.
Thus your `Factory` could have the following signature:

```
private IServiceHandler<TSale, TAudit>CreateHandler(FileType type)
```